# React JS java script - Iterate over map to check if product is added in the cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am no expert in React JS or Javascript. I am trying to disable a button when product is added in the cart. Is the code below correct?

```
<Button onClick={() => addToCart(product.productId)} className='btn-block' type='button' disabled={cart?.cartItems?.map((cartItem) => cartItem.productId === product.productId)}>
```

---

```
console.log(cart?.cartItems?.map((cartItem) => cartItem.productId)})
```

Prints 2 23 (two product IDS)

```
console.log(cart?.cartItems?.map((cartItem) => cartItem.productId === product.productId)})
```

Prints nothing when product.productID is 2. I expect it to print true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map()` does not exclude items when the callback function returns `false`, consider using [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which returns the object (`truly`) if it exist, or `undefined` otherwise (which keeps the button enabled):

```
cart?.cartItems?.find((cartItem) => cartItem.productId === product.productId)
```

Comment: Map won't do anything in this case since it does not look for a specific item in the array and simply returns a new array of the same length. `find` is a good way to solve this.

Comment: You're completly right, went to fast, changed my answer. Thanks @RubenSmn.

Comment: Thank you and much appreciated. This worked for me. Spent whole day trying to find the solution.